# Android on item click listener not working in webview inside gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, webview, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to setup on item click listener on gridview filled with multiple webviews.

```
    allBoardsGV = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.allBoardsGV);
    BoardAdapter boardAdapter = new BoardAdapter(this);
    boardAdapter.addAll(separateBoards);
    allBoardsGV.setAdapter(boardAdapter);

allBoardsGV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           Log.d("CLICK", "clicked");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowSingleBoard.class);
            startActivity(intent);
       }
   });
```

When I change WebView to TextView listener works, but with webview nothing happens.

Maybe anyone faced similar problem.
Thank you :)

Comment: what is allBoardsGV?

Comment: post your full code..

Comment: It is GridView which is filled with webviews by ArrayAdapter

Comment: Did you try to use allBoardsGV.setOnTouchListener instead of allBoardsGV.setOnItemClickListener ? You could try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4973621/3210173

Comment: may be that is forcusd set these attribute in gridview android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: @santoshkumar Yes I tried but no luck.
Touch listener not working too

I have tried onlongclick listener and that is the only one which works.