# GridView with the item of WebView doesn't respond setOnItemClickListener() method

Tags: android, gridview, webview, onitemclicklistener

I'm developing an e-book reader that will open epub files.In order to create links between table of contents i created new activity to show all of them.

---

[Here is the picture of my *MainActivity.class*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIYuq.jpg)

---

As can be clearly seen from the image i created gridview with the item of webviews.Becasue loading e-pub pages by means of webview is the easiest way.

---

Now,i'm experiencing a big trouble with this activity owing to clickable feature of the webview so that gridview can't respond the method setOnItemClickListener.

---

Now i'm sharing my code:

---

*MainActivity.class* and *activity_main.xml*

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    gridview.setColumnWidth(width / 2);

    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            // Pass image index
            i.putExtra("position", position);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

```js
 <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

---

And finally it is my *WebViewAdapter.class*

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import static com.tehedligmail.e_bookaz.LookAtAllChapters.height;
import static com.tehedligmail.e_bookaz.LookAtAllChapters.tinyDB;
import static com.tehedligmail.e_bookaz.LookAtAllChapters.width;

public class WebViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    // Constructor
    public WebViewAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tinyDB.getListString("BookSections").size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new WebView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final WebView SingleWebView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            SingleWebView = new WebView(mContext);


            GridView.LayoutParams GridviewLayoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(width / 2, height / 2);


            SingleWebView.setLayoutParams(GridviewLayoutParams);


        } else {

            SingleWebView = (WebView) convertView;

        }
        SingleWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", tinyDB.getListString("BookSections").get(position), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        
        return SingleWebView;

    }

   
}
```

Any suggestion will be welcome because i have already investigated lots of sites,please help me to solve the problem.*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Because you are loading url in every item so, what happen is in webpage there are so many links on that page so not easy to identify touch focus-ability. Please use long click listener. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135571/android-on-item-click-listener-not-working-in-webview-inside-gridview

Comment: Worked Like A CHARM,Thanks Too Much :)